# Error in retrieving rows from DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, ssis

Question - I get an error after the line `MessageBox.Show("for loop, last row..."); //TEST CODE` executes. What could be the cause ? When I get my result set from another database, there is no such problem. :( How do I fix this ?

Code -

```
    public void Main()
    {

        OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn col = null;
        DataRow row = null;
        string strCols = "";

        oleDA.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["MyResultSet"].Value);
        col = dt.Columns["MyColumn"];

        int lastIdx = dt.Rows.Count - 1;

        MessageBox.Show("int declared, for loop..."); //TEST CODE

        //loop upto 2nd last data row
        for (int i = 0; i <= lastIdx-1; i++)
        {
            row = dt.Rows[i];
            strCols += row[col.Ordinal].ToString() + ", ";
        }

        MessageBox.Show("for loop, last row..."); //TEST CODE

        row = dt.Rows[lastIdx];
        strCols += row[col.Ordinal].ToString(); //!!! I GET ERROR HERE !

        MessageBox.Show("strCols");

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

    }
```

Error -

```
Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position -1.
   at System.Data.RBTree`1.GetNodeByIndex(Int32 userIndex)
   at System.Data.RBTree`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Data.DataRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at My-Long-Code-Goes-Here.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

Comment: You don't have any rows in your `DataTable`

Comment: Okay, I got it. There were no rows in my result set because I had not done one variable mapping correctly. Once, i fixed that, my SQL was correct, i got a result set and my code works without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to fill your `DataTable` with an adopter which doesn't have any command object associated with it, that is why you are getting empty result back. You need to create a command object, then create the related `DataAdapater` and then use `Fill` method, something like:

```
OleDbCommand selectCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from yourTable", yourConnection);
OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand);
```

Comment: I am a new to C#. So, can you tell me a little more about what this means - You are trying to fill your DataTable with an adopter which doesn't have any command object associated with it, that is why you are getting empty result back ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing there are no rows being returned from your query.

Check `dt.Rows.Count`, verify that it's > 0.

Comment: yes, an if check shows that some queries don't have any rows. That was because of mistake in my dynamic query. Now, its fixed. Thanks.